# Magento Canonical Issue

Tags: url

I have an issue that I don't understand. I never did some code changes about it.

Problem is,  a normal magento site must go `www.site.com/xyz` when I type `site.com/xyz` in the address bar right?

Well its not working for me. I'm having 404 page I recently changed web-server to apache from **nginx**.

When I tried that on **nginx** `site.com/xyz` always redirected just `site.com`

its very confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Nginx was doing the www.site.com to site.com redirect for you. Now with apache you need to do the same, try to add this to your vhost file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```